# Multiple templates for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I know I can create multiple page templates for Pages by creating files like

```
template-page1.php
template-page2.php
```

And adding

```
/**
Template Name: Template 1
*/
```

At the beginning of file

Is there a way to do this for custom post type?

Comment: are you trying to display a custom post type posts on specific page template you've been created?

Comment: we could put it that way. I know that custom post type template is `post_type-single.php` but I was wondering if I could have more than one single template like with pages

Comment: you can create multiple page templates regularly and inside of them use the same post type in the array of "wp_query", then change the design or the differences you like to each of them.